# MongoDB - How to find the 10 largest values in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection named `crypto`, which contains cryptocurrency data that I pulled from an API call in a simple Express Node server. I want to be able to grab the 10 currencies with the largest USD value (so max 10 values in the collection), but I'm new to MongoDB and I don't really know how the query selectors work, and the documentation isn't very clear. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but did you try using `mongoose`? it makes interacting with MongoDB much simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.crypto.find().sort({"value":-1}).limit(10);
```

First you query your colelction without any param ( find() ), sort documents by value in descending order ( sort({"value":-1}) ) and limit the number of results to 10 ( .limit(10) )

I highly recommands you to look at [basic course of mongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about), it's free and perfect to start learning Mongodb. And there're more advanced courses if you need.